# How to Bind a TextView which is in an NavigationView in an Activity

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, navigation-drawer, butterknife

We are using android sdk 26 with butterknife 8.8.1

The `HomeActivity` has a navigation header, the navigation header also contains some text view. Is it possible to bind the `TextViews` in `HomeActivity` ?!

Here are some codes which describes my problem

The `HomeActivity` class has below layout

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout ....

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        .....
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer" />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

The nav_header has some TextView in it

```
<LinearLayout ....

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userinfo_vo_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Is it possible to bind the id of `userinfo_vo_name` text view in `HomeActivity`, the simple `BindView` fails

```
//fails 
@BindView(R.id.userinfo_vo_name)
TextView userinfoName;
```

Of course, I have called `ButterKnife.bind(this);` in `onCreate` method, but it seems not enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.yournavigationView);        
tvProfileName = (TextView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.tv_nav_userName);
imgUserProfile = (ImageView) navigationView.getHeaderView(0).findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
```

Comment: So it is not possible to use ButterKnife ?!

Comment: @Perm the post is for Oct 16, 2015, and I am using `Android support 26.1` Do you think the issue is not solved yet ?!

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi i don't i have also search about that issue but didn't fine related content about it in INTENET nor Stackoverflow

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi let me know it help you or not

Comment: not at work now, I'll come back to you as soon as I test it !

Comment: I asked a question https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1153 and got an answer and ask another question which remained on answer, I gone make it the correct answer but still looking for the answer of my question on git !

Answer (score -1):

Here is the way-

```
val headerView = binding.navView.getHeaderView(0)
val navHeaderBinding=NavHeaderBinding.bind(headerView)
navHeaderBinding.userinfoVoName.text = name
```